# How do I remove the circular dependency in my Organization-Owner-Member models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Heyo, I'm fairly new to this stuff so please pardon me if this is a stupid question. 
I'm trying to create an app where users can create organizations and join already existing ones. My requirements are:

- an organization may have only one user designated the owner (the user who creates it)
- users must be able to join several organizations
- users must be able to create organizations and therefore be owners of multiple organizations

So far I've got the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from myapp.users.models import User


class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Org(TimeStampedModel):

    name = models.CharField(
        _('Organization name'),
        max_length=255,
    )
    owner = models.OneToOneField('OrgOwner')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        'OrgMember',
        related_name='organization_members'
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        related_name='organization_users'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OrgMember(TimeStampedModel):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_profile'
    )
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Org,
        related_name='member_organization'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class OrgOwner(TimeStampedModel):

    member = models.OneToOneField(OrgMember)
    organization = models.OneToOneField(Org)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member.__str__()
```

My issue is that the way I've designed the models so far, I have a circular dependency. In order for a user to create an Org from scratch he needs to be an OrgMember of said, not yet created, Org. In other words, I cannot instantiate an OrgMember without assigning it an Org, but I cannot instantiate a new Org without an OrgOwner, for which I also need an OrgMember.

I'm sure there is just an error in my reasoning here. But perhaps there are some best practices for situations like this one you could share. There is probably a fairly simple solution to this, but I haven't been able to find one in an hour of searching and reading the django docs. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just have the owner field on the `Org` point to an OrgMember instead of `OrgOwner`? Also, what's the difference between org members and users? You can also add `null=True` to the owner field so that you can have someone create an org, become a member, and then set the owner field.

Comment: Also... Why does `OrgOwner` point to `Org` which already has an owner field. You're just repeating information over...

Answer (score 0):

I still can't see why you have so much looping information. Your `OrgMember` class has an organization field, even though `Org` already has a `ManyToMany` with `OrgMember`. Same thing with `OrgOwner` - except that points to `OrgMember` which already points to an `Org` as well. Both of those classes only have two fields - the `User` associated with it, and then the `Org`. Unless there are more fields, they serve no purpose - the same thing can be accomplished in one model:

```
class Org(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('Organization name'), max_length=255)
    # Only one owner, but each User can own more than one org
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='owned_orgs')
    members = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='organization_members')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='organization_users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'd recommend that you do some more reading [about Django's relationship fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did do some reading and trimmed that stuff out of the models. I still opted for a through-model, but got it working thanks to your comments.